# Gremlin ignoring store value

Tags: database, groovy, graph, gremlin

I am new to gremlin and trying out a query but as I observe store value is always ignored

I have tried `store`, `aggregate` and `as` as well but all are giving me false values.

`g.V().has('__typeName','avro_schema').where(local(out('__avro_record.fields').as('xm').local(out('classifiedAs').has('__typeName', 'DataClassification').count().is(eq(1))).count().is(eq(select('xm').size()))))`

this gives size of `'xm'` as always 0

I expect the value of size `'xm'` to be equal to the number of outgoing edges from each `avro_schema` with the edge label as `'__avro_record.fields'`

As pointed,changed the query to :

`g.V().has('__typeName','avro_schema').where(local(out('__avro_record.fields').local(out('classifiedAs').has('__typeName', 'DataClassification').count().is(eq(1))).count().is(count(local))))`

Now getting empty results.

Edit :

Also I have doubts related to printing of dynamic values as sideEffect

`g.V().has('__typeName','avro_schema').where(local(out('__avro_record.fields').local(out('classifiedAs').has('__typeName', 'DataClassification').count().is(eq(1))).count().sideEffect{ println count(local) }.is(count(local))))`

Output:

`[CountLocalStep]`

Where as I expect the actual value of count(local).What is the best practice to debug gremlin query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things that won't work in your traversal. First, `.size()` is not a Gremlin step, you're probably looking for `.count(local)`. Next, `eq()` does not take dynamic values, it only works with constant values. Read the [docs](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#where-step) for `where()` step to learn how to compare against dynamic values.

**UPDATE**

To compare the two `count()` values you would do something like this:

```
g.V().has('__typeName','avro_schema').filter(
    out('__avro_record.fields').fold().as('x').
    map(unfold().
        out('classifiedAs').has('__typeName', 'DataClassification').fold()).as('y').
    where('x', eq('y')).
      by(count(local)))
```

Comment: Updated the query..Now getting empty results.

Comment: You're still using `eq()`, although it's implicit now. `is(value)` is the same as `is(eq(value))`.

Comment: Still not very clear on how to compare two count() values where both are generated dynamically.  Is there a work around for this?

Comment: I just added an example.